# Working with UserID stored in a PHP Session once authenticated secure?

Tags: php, session

Currently my login form posts to php which returns a session 'authenicated' with a value of the user. Something like below.

```
if(Login Is Correct){
 $_SESSION['Authenticated'] = $UserID;
}else{
 //Login failed.
}
```

Then on the control panel for instance I would use the value of UserID to display the details of the user....

```
$UserID = $_SESSION['Authenticated'];
```

I know the data is stored on the server and just a cookie 'identifier' is kept on the client enabling it to obtain this information.

I also know potentially these cookies could be 'intercepted' but is this the 'correct' way to go about handling login and displaying logged in user data?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will get you what you need, so long as you are careful about how you handle session ID's.

There is an excellent article that covers some of the best practices you should be thinking about to ensure the safety of your customers here...
http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Are you using a framework with your PHP code? If so, make sure you check the frameworks support for sessions, as these will often include best practice measures built in. The other advantage of this solution is that someone that understand security will be maintaining it, for free!

Comment: It is ok. Just add some security for intercepting the cookie. Also from time to time check if user didnt changed something and you need to logout OLD session. - Like one year not seen session that suddenly appeard is quite strange.

Comment: On the topic of security when registering/logging in I am Ajax'ing the password (which displays in clear text via post) is this ok? Is the best way to post to a https location?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend doing sign-in and other account management tasks dealing with personal information over HTTPS.